# Find close pairs of real points in a set

Tags: algorithms

Given an array $S$ with $n$ real numbers. Design a linear time algorithm that finds $x,y \in S$ such that that $|x-y| \leq \frac{max(S)-min(S)}{n-1}$.

I was thinking that it is similar to the closest point problem but that can only be solved in O(nlogn).

Please help

Comment: Hint: Use buckets.

Comment: A pedantic answer: If $S \neq \emptyset$, let $e$ be any element of $S$. Pick $x=y=e$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: by the pigeon principle, if $n$ pigeons have to go into $n- 1$ holes, at least one hole has two pigeons in it. Now let your pigeons be numbers, and make sure that if two numbers go in the same hole, they solve your problem.